# MorphTo Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a MorphTo - MorphMany relationship such that an address can belong to a user or an organization. I keep getting the error

> Call to undefined method App\HTTP\Resources\User::singularLabel()

I tried to use a static method but that didn't seem to help. The code for the files is below.

Thanks

Address.php Model

```php
public function addressable()
{
   return $this->morphTo('addressable');
}
public function getHashidsConnection()
{
    return 'address';
}
```

User.php (Model)

```php
public function organisation()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Organisation');
}

public function addresses()
{
   return $this->morphMany('App\Address', 'addressable');
}
```

Address.php (Resource)

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),
        Text::make('line_1'),
        Text::make('line_2'),
        Text::make('line_3'),
        Text::make('post_code'),
        Boolean::make('is_primary'),

        MorphTo::make('Addressable')->types([ 
            User::class,
            Organisation::class,
        ])
    ];
}

public static function singularLabel()
{
    return Address::class;
}
```

User.php (Resource)

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        Gravatar::make(),

        Text::make('Name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),

        Text::make('Email')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'email', 'max:254')
            ->creationRules('unique:users,email')
            ->updateRules('unique:users,email,{{resourceId}}'),

        Password::make('Password')
            ->onlyOnForms()
            ->creationRules('required', 'string', 'min:8')
            ->updateRules('nullable', 'string', 'min:8'),

        MorphMany::make('Addresses')
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure you use nova ressource and not model for User and Organisation in Address.php (Resource) in the code below?

```
MorphTo::make('Addressable')->types([ 
  User::class,
  Organisation::class,
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MorphTo::make('Addressable')->types([ 
  UserResource::class,
  OrganisationResource::class,
])
```